# Lightswitch NullReferenceException for String in C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am sure this is a case of basic ignorance, but I'm trying to test a database value using code behind in a Lightswitch project.

I'm checking if a varchar(MAX) value is null

```
if (Order.OrderNotes.Equals(null))
{
     do.something...
}
```

However, I get a NullReferenceException if the value is null. If a value is there I get no error. I've tried using .contains(null), .Length = 0, .ToString() = "" etc without luck. It seems that ints and dates work fine using Equals(null), but not it seems for a string.

Help!!

Comment: What's null? Order? Or OrderNotes? The problem may be that you're trying to evaluate/call an extension method on the OrderNotes property of the Order object which might in fact be null itself.

Comment: The value in the database table Order, field OrderNotes which is a varchar(max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're calling this from a details screen where `Order != null` as @DeeMac pointed out.
You can check that `Order` isn't `null` using the same code below :

```
if (Order.OrderNotes == null) 
{
    // do.something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if OrderNotes is null, you can't call any method, properties or whatever using that instance

you should call

```
if (Order.OrderNotes == null)
```

of course I assume that the var Order is not itself null, 
if you want to be absolutely sure you could change your test in this way

```
if (Order != null && Order.OrderNotes == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In LightSwitch, to test if a nullable property has a value or not, you can use *HasValue*, so:

"if Order.OrderNotes.HasValue"

If you want the value if there is one, or the default value for the property type, you can use *GetValueOrDefault*:

"var value = Order.OrderNotes.GetValueOrDefault"

I agree wholeheartedly with Steve that you should be doing null checking on objects (such as Order) before trying to get a value from any of that object's properties.